# Show difference of CDFs has a global maximum

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $k(x)\geq0$ such that $\int_{\mathbb R}k(x)dx=1$, and define $K(x)=\int_{-\infty}^xk(y)dy$.

We can regard $k(x)$ as a probability density function and $K(x)$ as its CDF.

Let $a>b>0$ and $x_1<x_2$. Can we show that $f(x)=aK(x-x_1)-bK(x-x_2)$ has a global  maximum?

Observe that $f(-\infty)=0$ and $f(\infty)=a-b$. Here is an example when $k$ is the normal distribution:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It need not have a global maximum in general. See [this example](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/x5la8cpjpv) using the exponential cdf. However, for a particular class of CDFs, it's possible there is always a global maximum.

Note that you can easily compute the derivative by $f'(x)=ak(x-x_1)-bk(x-x_2)$, which could aid you in finding extrema.

Comment: A counterexample, nice! Although I would still be interested to know a necessary/sufficient condition, I will mark your answer since it answers my question.